# Return comments with WP-API Post data

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I'm using the [WP-API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) plugin as a RESTful API to my Wordpress site.  I want the comments associated with a post to return from the `/posts/:id` endpoint.  The [docs](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-a-post) indicate that this is possible by passing a `withcomments` filter, however I can't get this to work.  I've tried the following with no success:

http://climbingnarc.com/wp-json/posts/24001?filter[withcomments]=1

http://climbingnarc.com/wp-json/posts/24001?filter[withcomments]=true

I do know that http://climbingnarc.com/wp-json/posts/24001/comments works, but I don't want to have to make a separate request just for the comment data.

Is there a correct way to use this filter so that comments are returned with the post data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/766) about this and it was marked as `Enhancement`, so I'm assuming this just doesn't work at this point

Answer (score 2):

> Try `?_embed=1` in your request; that *ought* to bring down all embedded
>   data, including comments, alongside the requested post. — [**K.Adam White**](https://github.com/kadamwhite)

This works for me.

[Source](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/766)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13651969)

Comment: Are u blind? I did post the essential part to answer the question. If the site goes down this solutions will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. Working on a mobile app and don't want the users to make unnecessary API calls so I decided to make a plugin for.

https://github.com/shahin8r/comments-posts-wp-api

Let me know if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit after the fact, but this worked for me : "/wp-json/posts/{{post id}}/comments/". I'm a big fan of climbing narc! Hope this helps someone